# Query returning error in pyodbc but not in SSMS

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I've been working with python recently,
and try to connect data from several table from my sql server database by using this code:

```
query = textwrap.dedent('''SELECT
                     A.成形日, B.ライン, B.鋳込み回数, C.型番To AS 型番, A.組名 AS 組,
                     F.サービスタンク, F.泥温, F.比重, F.流れ, F.一分値, F.五分値, F.揺変性, F.加温巡回,
                     F.珪曹添加量,
                     C.品番, C.型使用回数, C.肉厚,C.内面硬度,C.外面硬度,C.脱型硬度,C.裏硬度,C.反転硬度,
                     B.鋳込み開始時刻,B.着肉時間,B.排泥時間,B.封入時間
                 FROM
                     IOT_T_SeikeiDailyReport AS A
                 INNER JOIN
                     IOT_T_SeikeiDailyReport_Line_Detail AS B
                 ON
                     (A.成形日 = B.成形日
                     AND    A.組名 = B.組名)
                 INNER JOIN 
                     IOT_T_SeikeiDailyReport_PartNo_Detail AS C
                 ON
                     (A.組名 = C.組名
                     AND    A.成形日 = C.成形日
                     AND    B.ライン = C.ライン
                     AND B.鋳込み回数 = C.鋳込み回数)
                 LEFT JOIN
                     IOT_T_SeikeiDailyReport_MoldingDefect AS D
                 ON
                     (A.組名 = D.kumi
                     AND    A.成形日 = D.molding_date
                     AND    B.ライン = D.line
                     AND    B.鋳込み回数 = D.ikomi
                     AND    C.型番To = D.kataban)
                 LEFT JOIN
                     IOT_M_KumiLineTank AS E
                 ON
                     (A.組名 = E.組
                     AND    B.ライン = E.ライン)
                 INNER JOIN
                     IOT_T_ServiceTank AS F
                 ON
                    ( A.成形日 = F.測定日
                 AND    E.タンク = F.サービスタンク)''')

    result = cursor.execute(query).fetchall()
```

and it's returning error:

> invalid syntax near '｢'

I thought that there are some syntax mistake on my code so I copied my "query" variable result and run it directly on sql management studio, but it returning result without any error.

Comment: Your query text contains unicode symbols. It looks like this is lost somewhere and read as non-unicode...

Comment: Hi Andrey, thank you for your reply. based on your answer I tried to encode my query before execute it on pyodbc. but it return with a different error "TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query."

Comment: Interesting that '｢' does not appear anywhere in your query. Have you tried without `textwrap.dedent` ?

Comment: yes, I've tried to concat the string using "+" but the problem persist, and so I tried to create VIEW table and change the column name to a normal alphabet and it works fine. I think it's encoding problem which `@AndreyNikolov said. also, if you use pymssql and not pyodbc this problem won't appear. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Japanese character which on my query.
I've tried to encode it first on utf-8 before execute the query but it didn't work.

so I created a view and change all the tables column name from Japanese to a a normal alphabet and it worked.
I also tried using pymssql instead of pyodbc and this problem didn't appear even if my tables column are in Japanese.

thank you.